# Animation on website

Tags: css, node.js, animation, mousehover

My client is looking for a website with animation. On the home page, an image of a sweet box will appear by default. When I hover on the sweet box, the box has to change color. When I click on a button 'Open', the sweet box has to open and show me the name of the sweet inside. Is it possible to do this animation? Can I use node js for this? Or, do you suggest anything lightweight? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this two libraries http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/ and https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ I think could be enough for you.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Victor Olivares. Will check them out.